# Can I determine the actual width/height of an element on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

To illustrate my question, here is a not-real example:

```
<img src='myimage-low.png' style='width: 150px;'>
<img src='myimage-high.png' style='width: 150px;'>
```

`myimage-low.png` is `150px` x `100px`

`myimage-high.png` is `1500px` x `1000px`

When I am zoomed all the way out on the web page, both images look the same. When I zoom in, the high definition image looks much better.

If I use javascript to get the image width with `$(elem).width();`, it says (as I would expect) `150px` for both, regardless of the zoom.

Is there a way in javascript to get the actual screen size of the element as presented to the user? In my above example, they might both say "100px" when I'm fully zoomed out, and "1000px" when I'm fully zoomed in.

Note - I need to be able to need this for both `<img>` elements as well as any element that might have a css `background-image`.

For context, this is to determine which resolution of an image to load. There's no point in loading the 1500px if the user is on a low resolution and it will just be resized in the browser to 300px - they might as well have the 500px version which is faster to download.

Comment: Also really depends on DPI etc.. what is “clear at one inch”?

Comment: Are you asking for pinch zoom? Or browser zoom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say hello to [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio):

```js
var el = document.querySelector('img');

function getElemSize(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    width: Math.round(rect.width * window.devicePixelRatio),
    height: Math.round(rect.height * window.devicePixelRatio)
  };
}

function updateSize() {
  var size = getElemSize(el);
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(size);
}

el.addEventListener('load', updateSize);
addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
```

```html
<img src="https://howitworks.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/214887-puppies-cute-puppy.jpg" style="width: 150px">
<p></p>
```

Comment: When running this in Chrome I get height of `0` after the first run, also the values don't change according to pinch zoom

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the first run (wasn't waiting for the image to be loaded). Oh, didn't think of pinch to zoom, sorry. I only know this technique for browser zoom

Comment: @awarrier99 Wait, don't accept if this doesn't work for your use (pinch to zoom). Maybe there is a better solution for that scenario

Comment: Oh I wasn't the original poster, I'm not sure whether they were intending for pinch zoom or not, and yeah first run looks good now

Comment: @awarrier99 Ah, I thought you were :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `visualViewport` API to multiply the width by the scale if you're looking for pinch zoom:

```
const { scale } = window.visualViewport;
const width = $(elem).width() * scale;
```

I tried adding a snippet for an example, but according to the spec the `window.visualViewport.scale` inside of an `iframe` is always 1. As long as your content is not in an `iframe`, this method will work for giving you the scale of the pinch zoom (tested in my browser console)